# How to plot a step response in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, signals, signal-processing

```
w=logspace(-2,2,100);
a=[1 (2/sqrt(2)) 1];   %coefficients of denominator for k=1
b=[0 0 1];    %coefficents of numerator for k=1
H1=freqs(b,a,w) %used to determine H(jw)in frequencies w

figure()
loglog(w,abs(H1).^20,'ro',10,10); %plot for H1

t=linspace(0,30)
step((b,a),t)
```

I want to determine the step response of the system in the array t and plot it. I am getting an error in the way I am inputing it. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

use `step(b,a,t);`.

`func( x, y, (a,b) )` is not a valid syntax in MATLAB, MATLAB doesn't have tuples.